# jQuery - Given a DIV with a bunch of <P> tags, how to find the first <P> that isn't empty

Tags: jquery, html

Given a DIV with a lot of paragraph tags:

```
<div>
 <p></p>
 <p>ADSADASAD ADS ADS  A </p>
 <p>ADSADASAD ADS ADS  A </p>
 <p>ADSADASAD ADS ADS  A </p>
 <p>ADSADASAD ADS ADS  A </p>
</div>
```

How to magically find the first `<P>` which isn't empty using just jQUery? ideas?

Comment: Over 500 questions and you **still** don't know how to format code in your questions?

Comment: @David Thomas - the formatting was so poor that 8 people edited the post, thus making it community wiki...

Comment: 8 edits and it's still 'jQUery'

Comment: ...good lord. Some people, huh? O.o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it a little less mind-bending to use methods rather than selectors for this:

```
$('div').find('p').not(':empty').first()
```

---

Edit: As per the poster's comment, here's a version that defines "empty" as "having no text content, although there may be HTML tags present":

```
$('div#foo').find('p').filter( function(){
  return ( $.trim($(this).text()).length ); 
}).first()
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8dem8j8L/

Comment: I'll take this as the answer, but it ended up not working for my use case which is TinyMCE, which while visibly empty still can contain HTML or HTML entities

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use:

```
$('div').find('p:not(:empty):first')
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how to use that. I'm getting all the HTML as a string via tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() which returns all these paragraph tags.

Comment: I tried   newNoteTitle = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();  
  newNoteTitle = newNoteTitle.find('p:first(:not(:empty))')
 but that errord

Comment: use `newNoteTitle = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent())`

Comment: no change:   newNoteTitle = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());  
  newNoteTitle = newNoteTitle.find('p:first(:not(:empty))').text();

Comment: You need to apply the `:first` *after* the `:not(:empty)` for it to work.

Comment: Returns empty ---   newNoteTitle = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
  newNoteTitle = $(newNoteTitle.).find('p(:not(:empty):first)').text();
  alert(newNoteTitle);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
var emptyP = null;
jQuery('div p').each(function() {
    if (emptyP == null && $(this).text() == '') {
        emptyP = this;
    }
});
```

**Edit:** tster's solution looks better, I didn't know about the `:empty` selector.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/8k3VW/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div p:not(p:empty):first').text('First not empty');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('div p:not(:empty)').eq(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following...

```
var firstNonEmptyP1 = $('p').not(':empty').first();
var firstNonEmptyP2 = $('p:not(:empty):first');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WTdMh/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not` selector with the `:empty` selector, like so:

```
var notEmpty = $('#container').find('p:not(:empty):first');
// or
var notEmpty = $('#container > p:not(:empty):first');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/omovu4)

The above uses an ID to find the container of the divs, but of course this is jQuery, you can use any selector.